# How to prevent any iframe or any other script to change title of document in the top window?

Tags: javascript, html

Normally, I just delete and re-define title property like the following code.

```
if (delete document.title) {
    Object.defineProperty(document, 'title', {
        get: getter,
        set: setter,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: false
    });
}
```

However, I found some page still can use the following code to change title.

```
$(window.top.document.head).find('title').text('New Title')
```

Is there any way to prevent it?

**Thanks,**

Comment: Maybe with iframe you can define a [`sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) attribute, without specifying `allow-top-navigation` but I don't know if that prevent what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook an observer to the title element. I modified [MDN's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) below:

```js
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementsByTagName("title");
console.log(target[0]);
 
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    alert("Title changed!");
 // Treat the mutation here. Use mutation.type to see what happened.
  });    
});
 
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target[0], config);

function changeTitle(){
 document.title = "Something else";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
 <title>A test</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="" onclick="changeTitle();">Change title</a>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
$("head title").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(e){ /* switch back to original title*/});
```